# Parse Twitter JSON Content in Ptython3

Tags: json, python-3.x

I searched for all similar questions and yet couldn't resolve below issue.

Here's my json file content:

https://objectsoftconsultants.s3.amazonaws.com/tweets.json

Code to get a particular element is as below:

```
import json


testsite_array = []

with open('tweets.json') as json_file:
    testsite_array = json_file.readlines()


for text in testsite_array:
    json_text = json.dumps(text)
    resp = json.loads(json_text)
    print(resp["created_at"])
```

Keep getting below error:

```
print(resp["created_at"])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Thanks much for your time and help, well in advance.

Comment: What is it you're trying to archive? The last three lines of your code don't make much sense.

Comment: Also, please provide a small excerpt from the json file embedded in the question instead of an external link.

Comment: I want to get only few elements from the raw twitter file. e.g. do sentiment analysis using twitter text

Comment: tried copying few lines from file here. it's too long to fit in here. thanks much for your time and help

Answer (score 0):

I have to guess what you're trying to do and can only hope that this will help you:

```
with open('tweets.json') as f:
    tweets = json.load(f)

print(tweets['created_at'])
```

It doesn't make sense to read a json file with `readlines`, because it is unlikely that each line of the file represents a complete json document.

Also I don't get why you're dumping the string only to load it again immediately.

**Update:**

Try this to parse your file line by line:

```
with open('tweets.json') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    try:
        tweet = json.loads(line)
        print(tweet['created_at'])
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        print('Error')
```

I want to point out however, that I do not recommend this approach. A file should contain only one json document. If the file does not contain a valid json document, the source for the file should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks much for your reply. I was trying several options, to make it work. Tried your approach and now getting below error:
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 3 column 1 (char 4798)

Comment: This means that your json file is not a valid json document.

Comment: Is there a way to iterate through the file and add only valid json lines in a collection like list or an array ?

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but I wouldn't recommend it. See my updated answer.